# Binding Toggle Button onClick to div

Tags: javascript

From previous threads I've used the following code.

Current code is available for review at http://jsfiddle.net/sLHKq/

```
<div id="question1">
<ol>
<li id="correct1">A1</li>
<li id="">A2</li>
</ol>
<div id="answer1" style="display:none;"></div>
<button onclick="toggle('answer1');">Button 1</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="question2">
<ol>
<li id="">B1</li>
<li id="correct2">B2</li>
</ol>
<div id="answer2" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle('answer2');">Button 2</button>
```

The Javascript I used is as follows for OnClick correct1 and correct2 id's in both divs are changing background color.I tried this code to achieve it for Only the respective Button's toggle to work.

```
function toggle(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if (e.style.display == 'none') {
e.style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("correct1").style.backgroundColor = '#BCF5A9';
document.getElementById("correct2").style.backgroundColor = '#BCF5A9';

} else {
e.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("correct1").style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
document.getElementById("correct2").style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';

}
}
```

How can restrict the onclick and background color change to just the question's button div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean like:

```
function toggle(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById("answer" + id);
    if (e.style.display == 'none') {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("correct" + id).style.backgroundColor = '#BCF5A9';
        document.getElementById("correct" + id).style.backgroundColor = '#BCF5A9';

    } else {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("correct" + id).style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
        document.getElementById("correct" + id).style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';

    }
}
```

See updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLHKq/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Sudhir for the code update, for some reason when I place this updated code in my site on localhost. It says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at `document.getElementById("correct" + id).style.backgroundColor`

Any ideas what could be the reason.

Comment: @Avil that would mean the code is not able to find relevant id, check if your id exists..

Comment: thanks, I got the error while testing. I found that If a new id=correct1 in question2 div is added. The code is adding it highlights only the correct2.

Would it require to create multiple functions with different parameter if there are different id=correct1,id=corect2 combinations in different question divs.

Question1 div has only id=correct1

Question2 has ids correct1 and correct2

Please advise.

Comment: @Avil ID's should be unique , it can be used only once per page..!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to pass correct answer id also in the function like this:

```
function toggle(id, ans) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'none') {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById(ans).style.backgroundColor = '#BCF5A9';
    } else {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(ans).style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
   }
}
```

check fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sLHKq/2/